# Concept of a derivative of an integral bounded by a function

Tags: derivatives, definite-integrals

When given the equation $\frac {d}{dx} [\int_0^{x^2}sin(t^3)dt]$, I know that the answer is $2xsin(x^6)$ and I know the process by which is it found, but I don't understand the concept.

The process that I used was:

a. let $f(t)=sin(t^3)$

b. $\implies \frac {d}{dx} [\int_0^{x^2}f(t)dt]$

c. $\implies\frac{d}{dx} [F(x^2)-F(0)]$

d. $\implies 2xf(x^2)$

e. $\implies 2xf(x^6)$

f. $\implies 2xsin(x^6)$

1. Why can I take the integral when it is $f(x)$ in terms of $dt$ in step b?
2. In e and f, why does the $t^3$ become $x^6$? Shouldn't it be $t^6$ since it is $sin(t^3)^2$? --answered
3. What is the point of this equation? An integral is the area under a curve, and a derivative is the slope of any point on a curve, but what would this equation be finding?
4. Why do you need to chain rule the derivative of $F(x^2)$ in step c to d?

Answer (score 2):

Well in (a) it should be $f(t)$, and so is (b). (e) is incorrect, and (f) you are just plugging in $x^2$ in $f(t)=\sin(t^3)$.

To answer question 3, it is not trivial problem since the upper bound of the integral is $x^2 \neq x$. It can be a good exercise for better understanding Leibniz integral rule. What it does is find the slope of $f(t)$ in terms of $x$ at the upper bound $x^2$.

4. Because you are taking derivative wrt $x$, not $x^2$ (echoes question 3.)

Comment: Ok all of that makes sense, but what even is the function finding?